# Java synchronized function unlock on callback

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I have a class with a `GetTemperature()` function that:

1. Connects to a device
2. Send a command to the device to read the temperature
3. A callback `OnGetTemperature()` is triggered when the temperature is read
4. In the callback, I disconnect from the device

This function is called from a React Native app in Android and can be called multiple times. I don't have access to the React Native app to limit the function calls.
The problem is that I want to make this function synchronous. Because only one connection can be active at a time.

I tried to make the `GetTemperature()` function synchronous but this function returns early and doesn't await the `OnGetTemperature()` so this didn't work.
Is there any way to lock the function and unlock it from the callback?
I tried the ReentrantLock to lock the class when the `GetTemperature()` is called and unlock it in the callback. But when the callback is triggered the app crashes. Maybe the object is locked and the callback cannot run from a different Thread?

Comment: what parameters OnGetTemperature has? Is there any object passed to command to read the temperature? I mean, how to distinguish different invocations of the callback function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Semaphone will do the the trick for you:

```
public class Test {

private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1); // Allow max 1 'palyer'

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    t.start(1);
    t.start(2);
    t.start(3);
    t.start(4);
}

private void start(int i) {
    try {
        semaphore.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("start " + i);
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            stop(i);
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}

private void stop(int i) {
    System.out.println("stop " + i);
    semaphore.release();
}
}
```

First time you call `start` acquire will increase the `semaphore's` count and then continue (printing "start 1" ect). Second time you call `start`, the execution will hold until .`release` is called, which will happen when "start 1"'s thread calls `stop` after 100 ms.

Output will be `start 1, stop 1, start 2, stop 2, ...` which is what you want. If you remove the semaphore the output will be `start 1, start 2, start 3, start 4, stop 1, stop 2, stop 3, stop 4` which is what you want.

In your case it is a callback that calls `stop`, not a thread, but I'm sure you still see what I mean.

For your solution to be complete, you need to add some error handling. For example, you cannot be sure that there will always be callbacks. So you probably want to call .`release` from `start` if `stop` has waited for the callback for eg 10 seconds.

Comment: One more thing... for the error handling to be 100% complete, you need to give each incoming call an ID, and when you release the semaphore you need to check if that ID has not already been released. Otherwise this scenario is not handled: Call #1 to start comes in, 10 seconds pass so start releases the semaphore, call #2 comes in, then the (very late) callback from call #1 comes in. In this case that callback should NOT release the semaphore, since the semaphore now "belongs" to call #2.